# Surface Pro 3 pen won't write, but top button works

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro

I was writing with my pen on my Surface Pro 3 when suddenly it stopped writing.

The eraser and select buttons on the side don't appear do do anything, and the screen doesn't detect it at all.

Strangely, the purple button at the top still works. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem with the following steps:

- Unscrew the pen and open it up
- Remove the AAAA battery
- Put the same AAAA battery back in
- Screw the pen back together

It works fine now, and I'm not entirely sure what went wrong, but perhaps this will be useful to others.

Comment: The pen itself seems to have two additional small batteries that supply the bluetooth module but dont deliver enough energy for the click-features. This makes the pen appear to work, if you just test it with the back-button... got me aswell