# Pen stylus on Surface 3 Pro doesn't work for drawing but works for clicking

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I have a problem with the pen. Apparently it's paired because clicking it pops out OneNote. However, when I try to work with it on the screen it doesn't register. Neither seem the two buttons on the side do anything. In fact, only the purple clicketty-click on the top produces anything noticeable.

I've followed [suggestion to replace battery](https://superuser.com/a/838844/161760), both resetting the old one and getting a totally new one. I've checked that Windows Update is up to date.

The only suspected thing is that in the settings for the pen, there's no options for the side buttons, only the purple one. Generally, there's seems to be very little settings for the pen to begin with.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did the touch screen perhaps get disabled in Device Manager under Human Interface Devices (HID-compliant device)?

Comment: @HighTechGeek I see *HID-compliant touch screen* and there are no warnings there. Also, note that I can write on the screen with my finger, so it seems to register.